# Delete all my YouTube content

Tags: youtube

I want to delete all my YouTube content including my uploads, likes, subscriptions and all. Also I tried deleting it from link -https://myaccount.google.com/deleteservices?pli=1

Everything was perfect, and I get the display content deleted successfully but still anybody find my content on net. I don't want anybody to see my content on net. Actually when anybody search YouTube with my name he gets into my YouTube page and can see my liked videos, but I want that nobody can see that. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is fixed by the link - https://myaccount.google.com/deleteservices?pli=1
.Actually if you want to delete the youtube content completely then first delete youtube a/c and then recreate it.

And the only way to delete your YouTube account is to delete the Google+ profile associated with it.

Deleting your Google+ account **will not affect** other Google products such as Gmail or Drive.
 Your emails and stored files will not be deleted. All photos uploaded to Google+ will still be accessible via Picasa.
You will not lose your contacts, though they will no longer be organized by Circles.
You will not lose any Google+ pages you own or manage.
You will lose access to your Google+ profile and all of your +1s.

Now to delete google+ a/c follow the link-http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-YouTube-Account

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete things like likes etc.

But you can delete your account and then recreate it. That way it won't be linked to you anymore.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip ! Can i delete only youtube from my google a/c.

Comment: Yes you can. Head to your profile on youtube and find the "remove account" button.

Comment: Sorry! but i am not getting the remove account option.

Comment: I get the option to delete Google+ a/c, but I dont want to delete gmail, is it possible?

Comment: I have deleted my Google+ account following the steps from- http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-a-YouTube-Account  . But still when i search youtube with my name, i can see my a/c.

Comment: It seems Youtube changed it once again. Can't find the option myself anymore either.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/2mzMwM8P3lI.  Someone else had the same, or a similar, problem, and eventually fixed it.  I confess I did not understand the instructions that resulted in success, and therefore I can't paraphrase or even paste them in here.

Comment: Yes, you can delete like. The videos you liked are grouped in a automatic playlist among the ones you created. You can delete videos from there ("unlike") just like form any other playlist.